# MySQL Locking Up INNODB Tables

Tags: mysql

My environment is Windows 7 and I'm using XAMPP.

I was doing some performance testing on MySQL simulating adding 100 rows at a time. I was doing this using a simple PHP query with for loops.

However, MySQL seems to have locked up as I can't add anything to the table anymore.

I logged into MySQL to look at the process list as below:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 1
   User: root
   Host: localhost:49349
     db: NULL
Command: Sleep
   Time: 2
  State:
   Info: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 17
   User: root
   Host: localhost:49759
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: NULL
   Info: SHOW PROCESSLIST
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried two things:

A. KILL QUERY 17 to which I got the following result:

`mysql> KILL QUERY 17; ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted`

B. Then I used the XAMPP controller to stop mysql and then start it again, but that didn't work as the table just seems to be locked permanently.

I also can't add data to the other INNODB tables in the database. MyISAM tables seems to be ok.

Is there a way I can force INNODB to just restart/reboot or something i.e. all queries and connections?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

It turns out this was a problem that was caused originally by the way I had PHP PDO for MySQL executing queries. I had set `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT = false` when I created the MYSQL connection (for some reasons I can't change), so I had to specifically run `$db_connection_handle->query('COMMIT;')` to specifically commit the transaction. So it appeared like the tables were locked.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: The last entry in the log file: `111019 14:39:41  InnoDB: Error: page 344 log sequence number 12784479
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 6540600.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.`

Answer (score 0):

- Check your logs. You may find that the ibdata file is full and can't expand or isn't set to auto-expand.
- Check `show innodb status` looking for active transactions. Example:

---

```
 ---TRANSACTION 0 16662058, ACTIVE 20 sec, process no 22014, OS thread id 140277380307216
 2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 30 row lock(s), undo log entries 30
 MySQL thread id 3662, query id 46913632 localhost user
 Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 16662059, sees < 0 16662059
```

---

Comment: Thanks. The log appears to show some corruption. The data seems to be intact. How do I recover database functionality as I can't do INSERTs or UPDATEs, only SELECTs (obviously on data that is not up-to-date).

Comment: @Obi http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html